# Preparing for deploying a console application (assembly fundamentals)

Tags: c#, deployment, console-application, .net-assembly

(new to .NET) I've built a small console application that uses a 3rd party data access component for Oracle (assemblies: devart.data.dll and devart.data.oracle.dll). I've been asked to gather environmental requirements for a new test server. On my local machine, I am able to simply copy the bin/debug or bin/release folder and my app just works. However, I doubt this will be the case on a new system. Obviously, I know I'll need the .NET 4.5 framework. But for this other dependency, I don't see these dlls in my folder. I'm not even sure how these were installed (I inherited this computer from a now-gone developer).

How do installations of 3rd party tools typically work with respect to deployments? How will I be able to say what's required and how to get it on the target machine?  Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your project references to see if the dlls are referenced in the project. If they are, you should be able to see the path they are located in. I'm guessing the dlls are on your network drive somewhere and your project is pointing to them.

You should be able to check all your references by right clicking on your project and selecting the "add reference" item on the menu. If the ddls are on your network drive, as long as the testing server has access to the file directory, you shouldn't need to worry about deploying the dlls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I go to references for the dll we are talking about and click properties, I can see a number of things. There is a "copy local" property set to false and an "aliases" property set to "global", among other things like version etc. And the path property is pointing to c:\program files(x86)\common\companyname\company.dll.  

So.. am I supposed to copy that dll into my own bin\release folder when I move it to the server? Or will the "copy local" property, if set to true, do this for me?  Or should I deploy this in a different way? I am looking for the simplest solution.

Comment: I noticed that both of these dlls are in the "Gac". So that's my question, how do I get these to be in the Gac or in the release folder of my app on the target machine? Will they be registered in gac automatically at runtime, do I have any control over this, etc? I would prefer to simply have what my app needs in the app's folder. I don't want unnecessary things in there.

I don't know why this has to be complex. I have the simplest app in the world that references 2 3rd party dlls. So what's the most straight-forward way to ensure that myapp has what it needs when I copy its release folder?

Comment: Great. All that work creating a question and it just dies. ugh.

Comment: If the dlls are in the GAC on the target machine you shouldn't need to worry about deploying the dlls with your project. If you want to deploy the dlls with your project, you can put the dlls in your bin folder and reference them in your project, but it is better to use the GAC as this allows version control on the dll  that the project are probably sharing.

Comment: Right, as I understand it now, .NET will always use the dlls it's looking for when it finds them, and it begins in the GAC, so if they are there it will always use those. 

I guess my follow-up question is, how do I ensure that this fresh machine gets these dlls installed properly in the GAC? Do third party tools typically have install programs or what? I know you can't answer for my particular case, but in general, how do 3rd party dlls typically get installed on a test or prod machine? It seems nowadays everyone uses lots of 3rd party stuff, so there must be an accepted way. Thanks

Comment: This is probably going to require some manual installs on your end if the needed dlls are not on your end. I may be wrong about this but I don't think there is an easy way to automate the deployment of dlls to the GAC. Even though this is for different dlls the deployment process should be similiar so this link might help you.http://www.telerik.com/blogs/working-with-assemblies-in-the-global-assembly-cache